# Conditional Formatting IF/AND (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm trying to highlight cells in column N when the following criteria are met:

- K = number (don't count text or blanks)
- N = blank
- L = date

Column K is formatted as a number

The formula I used: `=AND(K:K>0, N:N="")`

Unfortunately, if anything is filed in column K (text or number) and N is blank, then N is highlighted. How do I correct the formula for `K:K>0`? Is there a way to make it `ISNUMBER`?

I tried this formula, but it doesn't highlight anything
`=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(M:M), ISBLANK(N:N)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

`=IF( AND(ISNUMBER(K4), ISBLANK(N4), ISDATE(L4)), COUNTIFS(K4, ">0", L4, ">"&DATE(0,1,1)))`

It makes sure these conditions are met:

- K=number (not NA)
- N=blank
- L=date

Modified a formula @User0 provided. Thank you!